# NE555 monoflop only trigger once on power

Tags: dc, 555, monostable

I'm struggling more than I probably should with this simple sounding task:

The bell should be triggered once for about a half or 1 second when 12 VDC are applied.
I tried to solve this with a monoflop made from BC547 and a RC network but that dind't work. My second approach is now using a 555 which does work in general but I got two more problems:

1. For keeping the time short, I used a small cap and a small resistor for DISCHARGE and THRESHOLD. But the resistor is getting really hot, up to 60° C. Is there an elegant workaround for this?
2. Between power loss and the next power on cycle, I have to wait a few seconds until C2 is discharged enough, otherwise OUT won't get triggered.

How may I optimize the circuit?
Sorry for the likely bad circuit diagram ...

[image: Bell driver circuit]

Comment: You'd also want to add a decoupling capacitor to your NE555! People forget these, for some reason, but it's an IC that switches loads – you definitely need one.

Comment: Good to know! You mean between Vcc and GND?

Comment: Exactly. a simple 100 nF ceramic cap, mounted close to the VCC pin and with short connection to GND.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that the time constant of the trigger circuit (R2, R3, C2) needs to be shorter than the time constant of the timer itself (R5, C3).

Answer (score 2):

You have the timing capacitor C3 is connected to Vcc instead of ground, so fixing that would be the first ting to do.

At 12 V across 1 k, R5 would dissipate 144 mW maximum. You could use a larger resistance and smaller capacitance, or a higher wattage resistor, 1/4 W should be fine. I would go to 10 k and 470 nF, or 100 k and 47 nF

For triggering on power cycle, try C2 as 100 nF and R2 / R3 combined into one 1 Meg resistor. See if that solves your second problem.

Comment: Oops, the wrong placement of C3 is only a mistake in my diagram. It it is hooked up to GND instead of Vcc in my experimental setup. 
But using (ceramic) caps in nF range is a great idea! Will have a try, don't know why I never tried that. I already use those 1/4 W THT ones. Same for the auto-trigger RC network - in my head, the 4.7 µF elecrolyte caps were the lowest usable ones for whatever reason. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

this will get you about 530ms of pulse when the power comes on (subject to how precise your capacitor and resistor are), D1 is there to cause a reset if there's a brief outage of the power

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIYOtI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

this will get you about 530ms of pulse when the power comes on (subject to how precise your capacitor and resistor are),

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIYOtI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D1 is there to cause a reset if there's a brief outage of the power, this may require there to be an additional parallel load (to cause the 12V it to go to a low voltage), but the 555 itself will probably prove sufficient. Especially if it's the regular version with internal 15K resistance.

Comment: Alright that's a combined trigger/timing circuit like GodJihyo said? When power comes up, C2 voltage is lower than 2/3 of Vcc so OUT is high. And parallel C2 is charging via R2 until voltage on pin  6 (THRESHOLD) is higher than 2/3 of Vcc so the 555 will reset so I don't need to DISCHARGE through the 555?

Comment: This circuit works really well, thank you very much! I have to wait about 1 second before retrigger is possible, even when R2 being 220K instead of 470K. But the only 1 µF cap I found was a slow electrolyte capacitor. If I use a different type, this may mitigate the discharging time. But highest I found is 100 nF, this ain't enough. Will have a look and gonna try it!

Comment: Electrolytic should be plenty fast enough.  Is there a large capacitor connected in parallel with the 555 vcc-gnd?

Comment: You're right, I tried a different type and the problem persists. No, just a lab power supply. Plus I ommited the diode because it didn't work with that.

Comment: you may have had the diode connected backwards.   do you have a switch between the lab supply and the 555 ?

Comment: That's the solution! I added a switch and the circuit reacts perfectly fine and really fast! The PSU is just too slow - it discharges the output to zero instead of cutting it immediately. This keeps the cirucuit up. Never saw this as an option, thank you so much!